# Primefaces p:calendar and format user input into proper date

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, calendar, mask

Here's my problem:

I need a way to not validate (that's done already) but format/convert user input into this format: MM/dd/yyyy

Using JSF and Primefaces and sadly you can't use p:maskinput with p:calendar or my problem would be really super easy to fix.

I've searched and searched, and tried and tried many things to get it to work with no solution.

I believe my solution lies in this link: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Here's what the code looks like:

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{originalreturned}: " />

<p:calendar value="#{origReturnedDate}" 
            showOn="button" 
            pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" 
            showButtonPanel="true"
            navigator="true" 
            id="originalRetDate"
            onblur="formatDate(id);"
            size="10"
            yearRange="#{commonUtils.getCalendarRange()}"
            rendered="#{!isDocumentInquiryMode}">

    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"/>

    <f:attribute name="dateLabel" value="#{document_approved}"/>

</p:calendar>

<h:inputText id="date" value="#{origReturnedDate}" rendered="#{isDocumentInquiryMode}">  
     <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
```

I just don't know how to incorporate and use the plugin from the link above or if there is a different way I'm missing?

I've tried following the standards for JSF and PrimeFaces on importing an external .js file. But it doesn't work at all.

Thanks for any advice you might have for me

Example of plugin:
http://jsfiddle.net/smdvA/579/

Comment: What'g wrong with calendar's `pattern="MM/dd/yyyy"`? Is it not what you want? I don't understand the goal of your question..

Comment: Goal of my question is to convert user inputted data. They can user the calendar to select a date (works perfect) but when users enter in a date they have to enter it in exactly MM/dd/yyyy. Well I want to be able to enter in MMddyyyy and it auto format to MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's true that's too late but may be could help someone else . you can't use Mask but you can do it with regex expression  for exemple :

```
<p:calendar value="#{MyBean.MyDate}" id="MyCalendar"  effect="explode"  >
            <f:validateRegex pattern="^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$">
             <p:ajax update="msgMyCalendar" event="keyup" />   
           </f:validateRegex>
             </p:calendar>
              <p:message for="MyCalendar" id="msgMyCalendar" display="icon"/>
```